# Symfony 2.2.1 fatal error on remote server (only)-why?

Tags: symfony, cygwin, fosuserbundle, composer-php

On the Symfony codebase mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731796/symfony-2-2-1-rsync-deploy-not-working-on-remote-server), after installing FOSUserBundle, it  works locally, but on the remote server it doesn't even get to bootstrap, giving an HTTP 500 error page.

**Edit**: the disaster seems to happen at the following line in `app_dev.php`:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

On the remote server I get errors like:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request' not found in [docroot]/web/app.php on line 22
```

or- after deleting everything under the document root, updating (`composer update` and `composer update -o`,as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739798/719247)), and then deploying:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class 
Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Storage\\NativeSessionStorage in
[docroot]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
on line 25
```

I cleared the Symfony cache, deleted the `app/cache/dev` and `app/cache/prod/` directories, but no luck.

Another thing I don't get: `app/console cache:clear` on remote gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class 
EnhancedProxy_72114c0f8683bcc2a66ceccb136abe5a78f8577e\__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\SecuredController
in [docroot]/app/cache/de_/jms_diextra/proxies/Acme-DemoBundle-Controller-SecuredController.php
on line 28
```

BTW, why is the directory `app/cache/de_` (besides `dev` and `prod`) created?

For completeness' sake, you can find my `composer.json` [here](http://pastebin.com/1T6xwgcf).

What can be the problem? Local and remote platforms are different, but the errors seem to  relate to code, rather than server configs.

Local machine:

- Windows 7
- Zend Server CE
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3.14 (apache module)
- MySQL 5.1
- APC

Remote machine:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3.10 fpm (fastcgi)
- MySQL 5.5
- APC

Any suggestion? Even on how to debug this? I'm beginning to consider giving up Symfony :(

Comment: provide your composer.json please. Are you using APC/ ApcUniversalClassloader?

Comment: It seems like it misses some symfony2 components...

Comment: @nifr how can I check if I have ApcUniversalClassloader? From the standard install with vendors, I just added FOSUserBundle.

Comment: @PaoloStefan: Did you "copy" your entire app folder from local to remote?

Comment: @PaoloStefan: I've never had problem like those at deployment time. However, I remove cache folder explicitly (in deployment)

Comment: Also, did you delete your vendor/ folder before using composer update ? Sometimes, updates can fail and need a cleared vendor folder !

Comment: Try to delete whole `vendor/` folder, then copy to remote server `composer.lock` file, type `php composer.phat install`(not update) and tell if errors during installation

Comment: @forgottenbas Done on the local server-> worked locally. Then ran a deploy -> now it all works on remote too! Please post it as an answer (motivating this step, since I feel a bit lost :)

Comment: `de_` is the new name for `dev_new`, a temporary folder created during cache-clearing, according to notes in [this issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/96).  It's there because your cache-cache failed part way through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible reason that you have different version of vendors on your dev and prod servers. Then you run command `composer update` you update all vendors that you have. Sometimes it can crash everything. For that reason there is a command `composer install` that check your composer.lock file and install versions that you have there.

If you need to update only one bundle you can run `composer update bundle_name`. This action update your vendor folder and update composer.lock file too.

You can check [symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.2) repository, it has `composer.lock` file. Everytime you update vendors you must upload new version of that file to keep all your vendors the same version. Same story then you deploy your application.

You can read more about `composer.lock` file in [official documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file).

So, try to delete whole vendor/ folder, then copy to remote server composer.lock file, type `php composer.phar install`

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions could be

1. Composer wasn't finished (using `composer update` uses loads of resources, so always use `composer install` from lock file in remote environments). You should place the latest lock file from your local dev environment and reinstall. Also give the `--optimize-autoloader (-o)` param, as stated in http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install
2. You activated your apc cache in the config, but did not implement it correct in the startup file (usually `app.php`) in your /web directory. In that case, take a look at the APC enabled file in a fresh download, or https://github.com/dbu/symfony-project/blob/master/web/app.php. The commented parts should be un-commented.

Comment: Is the point #2 influencing the `app_dev.php` too? If not, it does not apply to the question. Thanks anyway - you made me discover somenthing :)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, it started with missing Request class but didn't end there. Turns out that my FTP clients (FileZilla and WinSCP) had issues transferring the remote server reporting success but resulting in 0 byte files (on Windows 7).

Tried a few things with transfer settings but no luck. WinSCP would at least report disconnect followed by a failed transfer due to file lock on remote machine. It resulted in a project being peppered with 0byte files and autoloader failures.

Switched to another FTP client (CoffeeCup FreeFTP) and it transferred ok, not sure at this time why the other clients had this issue, unfortunately hosting support wasn't able to explain it either.

Comment: Good to know, but I think it's not the case since I used Cygwin/rsync. THanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Go to:

```
 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
```

And change

```
protected $started = false;
```

to

```
protected $started = TRUE;
```