# Using rsync to deploy code updates for Symfony application

Tags: symfony, web-deployment, rsync

I have a couple of development machines that I code my changes on and one production server where I have deployed my Symfony application. Currently my deployment process is tedious and consists of the following workflow:

1. Determine the files changed in the last commit:

`svn log -v -r HEAD`

2. FTP those files to the server as the regular user
3. As root manually copy those files to their destination and, if required because the file is new, change the owner to the apache user

The local user does not have access to the apache directories which is why I must use root. I'm always worried that something will go wrong either due to a forgotten file during the FTP or the copy to the apache src directory.

I was thinking that instead I should FTP the entire Symfony `app/` and `src/` directories along with `composer.json` to the server as the regular user then come up with a script using rsync to sync all of the files.

New workflow would be:

1. FTP app/ src/ composer.json to the server in the local user's project directory
2. Run the sync script to sync the files
3. clear the cache

Is this a good solution or is there something better for Symfony projects?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731796/symfony-2-2-1-rsync-deploy-not-working-on-remote-server) is similar and gives an example of the rsync, but the pros and cons of this method are not discussed. Ideally I'd like to get the method that is the most reliable and easy to setup preferably without the need to install new software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically every automated solution would be better than rsync or ftp. There are multiple things to do as you have mentioned: copy files, clear cache, run migrations, generate assets, list goes on.

Here you will find list of potential solutions.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#using-build-scripts-and-other-tools

From my experience with symfony I can recommend capifony, it takes a while to understand it, but it pays off

Comment: I had a look through and I probably will be going with one of the php deployment tools, but your information has helped me decide so I'm marking this as the correct answer.